# How to delete packages in without opening Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, package

My project doesn't opens after added texture pack from asset store.
It's Stucking on Initial **Asset DataBase Refresh**.
I'm guessing it'll open after deleting that package.   Added
But I couldn't find information about how to delete packages without opening Unity.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you using source control? If not, now is a good time to start, it makes this so much easier. You could just revert back to a known good state and move on. Assuming you're not the first thing I would do is make a backup copy of your project in case you make things worse. Then I'd delete the Library directory and try opening it again. This may take some time as it will need to reimport things but could help. If not then I'd look at the [editor.log](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) file for more information.

Comment: How long have you waited for it to open? If you added a bunch of textures it may just be taking some time to import and compress them.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have my project in Github and I did a lot of work on the project after added texture pack. And unfortunetly I commited all that changes to Github. When I'm adding my project from there to my PC, this problem is appearing again and again but when I'm adding for the first time it's taking for about 7-10 minutes to open. The following attempts opening the project is taking 30-40 seconds

Comment: Then go back a commit.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the best bet is using a previous revision where you don't have the dependency. If that is not an option, try entering the project in Safe Mode.

The easiest way to get Safe Mode is to get a compilation error. What you can do is edit a class in notepad (or whatever text editor you prefer) that is explicitly referenced (like a manager such as `InventoryManager` or whatever class you have in your game) and to reduce the impact just add a `2` in the name (for example `InventoryManager2`) but without updating any calls to it. Then open the project and when Unity prompts you that the project cannot be opened because of errors, pick Safe Mode.

From there you can manipulate packages. Keep in mind that in Safe Mode the assets will appear invalid or disabled (for example Scenes might appear empty). Once you uninstall the package, save the project, fix the compilation error and reopen it.

Obviously, for safety, make a back-up.